# CAST/CONVERT Datatype to INT SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014, I have stored procedure and a SSRS report with dataSet which connects to it. DataSet query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Test10 
FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER1], 'exec [test_1].shp.Report_test1 @FIELDID = [@FIELDID]')

SELECT * FROM #Test10
```

So when user types number in parameter `@FIELDID`, he gets an error

> Converting data type nvachar to int.

I need to convert data `@FIELDID` in this query to INT. Hope for help with correct syntax.

Comment: why not have it as an int in your SSRS parameter instead?

Comment: changing datatype to integer in report paramater properties doesnt help, have the same error which i wrote above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building the scenario, i have created a table sample in the schema .dbo  And created the procedure Report_test1 in the schema .shp .

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[sample]
(ID INT,
 Name VARCHAR(50))
 GO

 INSERT INTO  dbo.sample
 VALUES (1,'A'), (2,'B'), (2,'C'), (1,'D'), (3,'A'), (1,'F')
 GO

CREATE PROCEDURE shp.Report_test1
@FIELDID int
AS 
BEGIN 

  SELECT *
  FROM [Sample]
  WHERE id=@FIELDID

END
GO
```

Then i ran the below openquery command and it works for me..

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @FIELDID INT=1

SET @Query = N'SELECT * INTO dbo.Test1 FROM OPENQUERY([LAP], ''exec  [MyLab].shp.Report_test1 @FIELDID = '+Cast(@FIELDID As Varchar(50))+ '  '')'
EXEC (@Query)

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test1
```

Try like this and let me know.

Comment: mssql says - Could not find stored procedure ''.

Comment: Did you mentioned your server name?

Comment: OPENQUERY([Server] - if you are talking about this part of query, yes I did

Comment: I tried to create your scenarion and its works for me.. Just check the updated script and let me know.. make sure the procedure sxists in the schema .shp